# jQuery two mouseenter events, fire one function ONCE

Tags: jquery, bind, mouseleave

I bound a mouseenter/mouseleave event to an element (just an image), which in turn executes two functions. My issue is that I want one of the two functions to ONLY fire once on the first mouseenter.

aka on the first mouseenter two things happen, on the second mouseneter only one thing happens.

```
$(.bubbles).mouseenter(function(){
    functionSwapImage();                         //this should happen everytime
}).mouseleave(function(){
    functionSwapImageBack();                     //this should happen everytime
    $(".bubbles").one("mouseleave", function(){
        myFunction();                            //this should happen once!
    });
});
```

EDIT:  http://jsfiddle.net/Am5ZC/

If I move the `.one` function outside of that block and into its own separate mouse enter/leave block, then the `functionSwapImageBack()` only fires once (ie, .one is removing the event for both blocks of code).

Not really sure how to go about this but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using namespaced events which remove only that specific event handler with namespace.

```
$(".bubbles").mouseenter(function(){
    functionSwapImage();                         //this should happen everytime
}).mouseleave(function(){
    functionSwapImageBack();                     //this should happen everytime
}).one("mouseleave.onlyonce", function(){
    myFunction();                            //this should happen once!
});
```

Comment: looks good, but you need to move the `one` function outside of the block. Otherwise it will be bound again every time the mouse leaves

Comment: do i have to edit the html? what do i do with the "onlyonce" namespace ? ie, `myFunction() { console.log("good"); }` what should that look like ?

Comment: I have just edited my answer where I moved `one` outside `mouseleave` handler. Did you updated your code?

Comment: As mentioned by @FelixKing, `one` has issue in 1.7.1. If you change it to 1.7 it works fine take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Am5ZC/1/.

Comment: If you want to use 1.7.1 only then I have a work around for `one` take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Am5ZC/2/

Comment: so your answers are essentially the same at this point. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('.bubbles').one('mouseleave', myFunction)
.mouseenter(functionSwapImage)
.mouseleave(functionSwapImageBack);
```

Don't know if you want to bind it to the `mouseleave` or `mouseenter` event.

**Update:** It appears to work properly in [jQuery 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/wjr4z/) but not in [jQuery 1.7.1](http://jsfiddle.net/wjr4z/1/). It seems to be a bug.